# Is there a way to enable inlay hints in VSCode for other languages like Java?

Tags: python, java, visual-studio-code

I noticed that inlay hints have been added to VSCode for TypeScript and JavaScript. I was just wondering if there was a way to enable it for languages like Java and Python just like IntelliJ does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code Java@1.5.0 has supported inlay hint, which can be controlled by the setting `java.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled`.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is in the plan, see [support inlay hints](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2099).

You may upvote it and waiting for the feature released.